# Animation with display flex

Tags: angularjs, css, ionic-framework

When I open the item-accordion I have used the animation .But the item-accordion has the image that is wrap in the multiple row using display flex property of the CSS3. Whenever I open the accordion the extra content is displayed on the right during transition.So can anyone suggest what can be done to solve it?And this happens when width of the content is small

Another problem is i have used the animate-repeat animation to delete the item.But when i open the item-accordion the animation is applied to them also hence animating the image as a list.

```
.list .item-accordion {
  -webkit-transition:0.09s all linear ;
  transition: 0.09s all linear;
}
```

This is the animation I am using.

The demo of the code is over here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/FnQVCYrSGOlpk5wNxAZ6?p=preview

Comment: Animating flex items often involves setting a basis. They don't animate well if you don't specify any sizes. Play around with that a bit first.

Comment: ok but my requiremnt is i dont want to fix the size

Comment: The problem is browsers can't animate height or width of "auto". You aren't using flex to layout vertically you are doing it as a row and letting it wrap. Which really defeats the purpose of using flex at all. The only way I've ever been able to do this is with javascript that checks the current height of the item, sets that height, gets the new content and while hidden (opaque) checks the height of that content and then sets that height.

Comment: You can however try this trick: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animating_height/

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues when having to meet complex animation requirements.  I have used greensock for more complex animations but that doesn't seem to be needed here.  The general concept is that you are going to want to animate something but change/alter the properties before and after the animation has completed.  You are going to have to be using a few callback promises to run additional animation after the first part of the animation has completed or do some manual calculations and adjust properties before starting or ending.

[Angular Animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate)

[Ionic Animate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicAnimation/)

It seems like ionic is allowing for onStart and onEnd callbacks.  I would hide or force certain properties onStart and reset them onEnd so that you can get around what you are trying to work with.  If you are not wanting to work with a fixed width or height you are going to have to grab window/screen size and so some basic calculations based on that.  So you would get your window size set the size based on the window for the animation then reset back to auto when completed.